# How do I view Windows 8 calculator shortcut keys?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, calculator

Basically the subject says it all. Viewing help, doesn't help (ironically) since it shows just some *Calculator: Frequently asked questions*.

Comment: WHat kinds of shortcuts are you trying to perform? Of course the number keys enter numbers, and `* / + - =` all work as expected. What functions do you want shortcuts to?

Comment: All the functions of scientific calculator, for example `y` is a shortcut for exponent, `s` is sine, etc. I remember most of'em but forgot some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's weird that this isn't in the help file, you're right. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts has a very extensive list of shortcuts for the calculator (as well as other things).

```
Alt+1           Switch to Standard mode
Alt+2           Switch to Scientific mode
Alt+3           Switch to Programmer mode
Alt+4           Switch to Statistics mode
Ctrl+E          Open date calculations
Ctrl+H          Turn calculation history on or off
Ctrl+U          Open unit conversion
Alt+C           Calculate or solve date calculations and worksheets
F1              Open Calculator Help
Ctrl+Q          Press the M- button
Ctrl+P          Press the M+ button
Ctrl+M          Press the MS button
Ctrl+R          Press the MR button
Ctrl+L          Press the MC button
%               Press the % button
F9              Press the +/– button
/               Press the / button
*               Press the * button
+               Press the + button
-               Press the – button
R               Press the 1/× button
@               Press the square root button
0-9             Press the number buttons (0-9)
=               Press the = button
.               Press the . (decimal point) button
Backspace       Press the backspace button
Esc             Press the C button
Del             Press the CE button
Ctrl+Shift+D    Clear the calculation history
F2              Edit the calculation history
Up Arrow key    Navigate up in the calculation history
Down Arrow key  Navigate down in the calculation history
Esc             Cancel editing the calculation history
Enter           Recalculate the calculation history after editing
F3              Select Degrees in Scientific mode
F4              Select Radians in Scientific mode
F5              Select Grads in Scientific mode
I               Press the Inv button in Scientific mode
D               Press the Mod button in Scientific mode
Ctrl+S          Press the sinh button in Scientific mode
Ctrl+O          Press the cosh button in Scientific mode
Ctrl+T          Press the tanh button in Scientific mode
(               Press the ( button in Scientific mode
)               Press the ) button in Scientific mode
N               Press the ln button in Scientific mode
;               Press the Int button in Scientific mode
S               Press the sin button in Scientific mode
O               Press the cos button in Scientific mode
T               Press the tan button in Scientific mode
M               Press the dms button in Scientific mode
P               Press the pi button in Scientific mode
V               Press the F-E button in Scientific mode
X               Press the Exp button in Scientific mode
Q               Press the x^2 button in Scientific mode
Y               Press the x^y button in Scientific mode
#               Press the x^3 button in Scientific mode
L               Press the log button in Scientific mode
!               Press the n! button in Scientific mode
Ctrl+Y          Press the y√x button in Scientific mode
Ctrl+B          Press the 3√x button in Scientific mode
Ctrl+G          Press the 10x button in Scientific mode
F5              Select Hex in Programmer mode
F6              Select Dec in Programmer mode
F7              Select Oct in Programmer mode
F8              Select Bin in Programmer mode
F12             Select Qword in Programmer mode
F2              Select Dword in Programmer mode
F3              Select Word in Programmer mode
F4              Select Byte in Programmer mode
K               Press the RoR button in Programmer mode
J               Press the RoL button in Programmer mode
<               Press the Lsh button in Programmer mode
>               Press the Rsh button in Programmer mode
%               Press the Mod button in Programmer mode
(               Press the ( button in Programmer mode
)               Press the ) button in Programmer mode
|               Press the Or button in Programmer mode
^               Press the Xor button in Programmer mode
~               Press the Not button in Programmer mode
&               Press the And button in Programmer mode
A-F             Press the A-F buttons in Programmer mode
Spacebar        Toggles the bit value in Programmer mode
A               Press the Average button in Statistics mode
Ctrl+A          Press the Average Sq button in Statistics mode
S               Press the Sum button in Statistics mode
Ctrl+S          Press the Sum Sq button in Statistics mode
T               Press the S.D. button in Statistics mode
Ctrl+T          Press the Inv S.D. button in Statistics mode
D               Press the CAD button in Statistics mode
```

Comment: It's there in Calc's help file in Win7 (F1 / click [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmCz.png), see [list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ogqgR.png)); am surprised it's not there in Win8.

Comment: @Karan Ooh, good call! The Windows 8 `Keyboard shortcuts` help page still has it (start -> type "help" -> hit enter -> search for "shortcuts")

Comment: I'm guessing no other answers are required or will be posted, so that extra-lengthy image shouldn't really matter. However if someone objects it can always be deleted.

Comment: Edit: I put in the raw html version, figured it's less obnoxious without the CSS

Comment: @nixda Thanks :) How'd you get the spaces inserted, by the way?

Comment: @MarcusChan  If you copy from a Microsoft website, always use Internet Explorer. You will be surprised ;)